# HOW to solve the point in Regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

the file is:

```
google.com a
go.gle.com a
google.com.google.com b
google.com.cloud.com c
```

when I use this way:

```
grep -nre  '^\<google.com\> ' file<br>
```

I can get:

```
1:google.com a
```

But the way:

```
grep -nre  '^\<go.gle.com\> ' file<br>
```

also get :

```
1:google.com a
2:go.gle.com a
```

I want to the result from the " `grep -nre  '^\<go.gle.com\>` ' file " is:

```
2:go.gle.com a
```

**NOT**

```
1:google.com a
```

How to solve it?
**PS： the domain name in grep command like "google.com" is not fixed. maybe "goog.e.com" or ".oogle.com"**

Comment: Escape the dot: `\.` http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for (**literal match**) is not possible with your `grep` options because `grep` will treat `matching pattern` as RegEx and hence dot will mean `any character`.

You can use -F switch in `grep` OR use `fgrep` for `fixed string match` like this to get your result:

```
grep -nF 'go.gle.com ' inFile
```

OR:

```
fgrep -n 'go.gle.com ' inFile
```

**Alternatively** following awk command will give you the output you're looking for:

```
awk 'index($1, "go.gle.com"){print NR ":" $0}' inFile
```

OR for exact match:

```
awk '$1 == "go.gle.com"{print NR ":" $0}' inFile
```

Note that I'm using `awk's index function` or comparing equality `==`, hence matching string is not considered a RegEx.

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/FL37Sx

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match the dot literaly, you have to escape it

```
grep -nre  '^\<go\.gle\.com\> ' file<br>
```

[The `.` is a special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in regex and matches every character except newlines (by default, means without modifier)

Another possibility would be to put the dot into a character class, some people like this notation better:

```
grep -nre  '^\<go[.]gle[.]com\> ' file<br>
```

inside a character class a dot is also only a dot.

Comment: the domain name in grep command like "google.com" is not fixed. maybe "goog.e.com" or ".oogle.com"

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem. What do you want to find and what can change.

Comment: I want "grep -nre '^\<go.gle.com\>" just go.gle.com  not google.com But not use "\",  This is possible ?

Comment: `.` without escaping will match any character, so it will match the "o" also. Another possibility would be to put the dot into a character class `grep -nre  '^\<go[.]gle[.]com\> ' file<br>`, some people like this better.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to escape the period. Try `grep -nre '^\<go\.gle\.com\>' file`.

To match only mis-spellings of `google.com` where the second "o" is incorrect, you could use a character class that matches anything *except* "o":

```
grep -nre '^\<go[^o]gle\.com\> ' file
```

Extending that to account for any one of the first five characters being incorrect:

```
$ grep -nre '\([^g]oogle\|g[^o]ogle\|go[^o]gle\|goo[^g]le\|goog[^l]e\|googl[^e]\)\.com' file.txt 
2:.oogle.com a
3:gRogle.com a
4:go.gle.com a
5:goonle.com a
6:googqe.com a
7:googla.com a
```

Comment: thank you. But  the domain name in grep command like "google.com" is not fixed. maybe "goog.e.com" or ".oogle.com"

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by this comment. Do you need it to also match `goog.e.com` and `.oogle.com`?